# Is there package to neatly render a description of a library API

Tags: packages

For various reasons, I can't use documentation tools like readthedocs to document an API. I therefore would like to know if there is a LaTeX package that I could use to render a similar style but written purely in Latex. There does't need to be hyperlinks in the documentation. An example style (or something similar) would be:

[image]

Comment: you could do something similar with tcolorbox, or look at the latex generated by sphinx and write a document in the same style directly.

Comment: That's what I am currently trying, I just thought there may have been a package already available.